# Router page opens while I'm away

Tags: networking, router, security

I have a Windows 10 machine that I use as my main personal computer.  Maybe this doesn't matter, but it's **not** an activated copy.  I usually leave my computer powered on and just turn the monitor off.  When I sit at my desk, I turn the monitor back on.  I also normally leave Chrome up with a few tabs open.

A few times during the last month or so, I've noticed when I get back to my desk, my router page is open in a new tab in Chrome.

The URL looks like this: http://router/000-Dashboard.htm

I have a password set, so nothing can looked at or modified without a password.  I did a scan with AVG and everything checks out.  I haven't noticed any other performance issues.

I've scoured Google the best that I know how and can't find anything on this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Perform a hard reset of the router.

Comment: I will try that this evening and post back if it works.  Unfortunately, since it happens so infrequently, it'll be a long test.